# How to add zoom transition effects using FFmpeg to a variable number of images?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I add add zoom transition effects using FFmpeg to a variable number of images?

I am able to create video from a variable number of images but I am not sure how to add zoom in and out transition effects between images:

```
 ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i img%03d.jpeg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

I found this,

https://superuser.com/questions/1189246/ffmpeg-image-slideshow-with-zoompan-and-fade-in-out/1190199

But problem is that images are hard coded in that example and I am not sure how to make it work for a variable number of images?

Comment: Do you need the fade as well?

Comment: @Gyan would it be possible to have few effects available and randomly choose one or another